# Problema al tratar de enviar un email utilizando Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema al tratar de enviar un email utilizando Django...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Use estas configuraciones en el archivo settings:

- EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
- EMAIL_PORT = 587
- EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'dukleenteam@gmail.com'
- EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
- EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

Y use estas cofiguraciones en el archivo de views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.conf import settings


# Create your views here.
def send_mail (Email,Name,Message):
  context = {'Message': Message, 'Name': Name, 'Email': Email}
  template = get_template ('correo.html')
  content = template.render(context)
  emailEnviado = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    'Un correo de prueba', #Titulo del correo
    'Lo que sea', #Descripcion del Correo
    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    [Email],)

  email.attach_alternative(content, 'text/html')
  email.send()

def index (request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    
    Name = request.POST.get('Name')
    Email = request.POST.get('Email')
    Message = request.POST.get('Message')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'Name': Name})

    #send an email
    send_mail (Email,Name,Message)

  else:
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Sin embargo el correo enviado no llega ami bandeja de entrada.. no se que pueda estar pasando... en la imagen muestra lo que sale en la terminal despues de intentar de enviar el email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la [documentación](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials&visit_id=637509510983863986-1769018723&rd=2#cantsignin) piden otro `EMAIL_HOST`.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

> El siguiente paso te lo pide el manual de ayuda de google, pero he verificado que sin el puedes igualmente

Asegura que tienes el IMAP activado en Google --> `Bandeja entrada gmail` > `Mostrar configuración` > `Reenvio y POP/IMAP` > `Descarga POP activa`.

Asegura por ultimo que tienes permitido el acceso a [aplicaciones poco seguras](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) ( paso 2 punto 3)

Ahora puedes testear el envio de email abriendo una consola django `./manage.py shell` y ejecutando:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('hola','com estas? Muy bien!','correo.origen@gmail.com',['xxxxx@xxxx.es'])
1
```

El `1` final indica que se ha enviado satisfactoriamente. Caso contrario te mostrará el error.

Caso contrario te muestrará un error como ese, cuando no tenia activado el acceso aplicaciones menos seguras.

```
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials j20sm6892759wmp.30 - gsmtp')
```

Te dejo el link de la [documentación de Django sobre enviar emails](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/topics/email/)

Te recomiendo utilizar tu `gmail` para enviar correos solo para medios formativos, bajar el nivel de seguridad de `google` no es nada recomendable. Para enviar correos hay soluciones muy buenas y gratuitas ( usuario con poco uso) como [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/), y muchas mas que no conozco, que te habilitan una API en lugar de SMTP, que funcionaran mucho mejor.